# GRASS function "V.net.centrality" Error env: python3: No such file or directory

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am using QGIS 3.4 (just updated) on a Mac OSX Mojave 10.14. I am trying to use the grass function "v.net.centrality" but I keep getting an error. The error is ... env: python3: No such file or directory. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Is the Python3 package actually installed on your system?

Comment: I downloaded Python 3.6 or 3.7 today. IS that what you are referring to?

Comment: any ideas here??

Comment: If you need Python3 support in GRASS GIS then version 7.8 will officially support it (however, the current development version GRASS GIS 7.7 is on the way to support it, you may try with that)